# Why is my UIButton not showing up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

This is the code I'm using:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 70)];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    if (buttonArray == nil) {
        buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [buttonArray addObject:button];
    [button release];
```

The butting isn't displaying, however. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 8):

You're initializing it wrong. Try the following:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 70);
[self.view addSubview:button];
if (buttonArray == nil) {
    buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[buttonArray addObject:button];
```

Comment: I do not think that you should be releasing 'button' if you initialize it this way.